# convert txt to sitemap.xml with PHP

Tags: php, xml, text, sitemap, sitemap.xml

Supposed that I have text database include is:

```
http://example.com,monthly,0.3
http://example.com/one,daily,0.5
http://example.com/two,weekly,0,8
```

I would like to convert to my text database to sitemap.xml.

```
$fp = fopen('./database.txt', 'r');
$xml = new XMLWriter;
$xml->openURI('./sitemap.xml');
$xml->setIndent(true); 
$xml->startElement('urlset');
while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
   if (count($line) < 4) continue;
   $xml->startElement('url');
   $xml->writeElement('loc', $line[0]);
   $xml->writeElement('changefreq', $line[1]);
   $xml->writeElement('priority', $line[2]);
echo $xliff->getDocument();
   $xml->endElement();
}
$xml->endElement();
```

I tried this code, I couldn't add this part...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset 
  xmlns='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9' 
  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'     
  xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-start-attribute-ns.php
or use DOM:

```
$fp = fopen('./database.txt', 'r');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$urlset = $dom->createElementNS('http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9', 'urlset');
$dom->appendChild($urlset);
while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
    var_dump($line);
    $url = $dom->createElement('url');
    $urlset->appendChild($url);
    $url->appendChild($dom->createElement('loc', $line[0]));
    $url->appendChild($dom->createElement('changefreq', $line[1]));
    $url->appendChild($dom->createElement('priority', $line[2]));
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `xmlns='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'` is a namespace definition. It defines that all element nodes (without a prefix are part of this format. You can read the element tag names as `{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}:urlset`, `{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}:url`, ...

It allows to mix XML formats without conflicts.

To create an XML node with XML reader that need a namespace definition you will have to use the *NS variants of the methods. This is a little different from DOM, where you always provide the namespace and it adds namespace definitions as needed.

```
$csv = <<<'CSV'
http://example.com,monthly,0,3
http://example.com/one,daily,0,5
http://example.com/two,weekly,0,8
CSV;
$lines = array_map('str_getcsv', explode("\n", $csv));

$xmlns = 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9';
$xml = new XMLWriter;
$xml->openMemory();
$xml->setIndent(true); 
$xml->startElementNS(NULL, 'urlset', $xmlns);
$xml->writeAttributeNS(
  'xsi', 
  'schemaLocation', 
  'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
  'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd'
);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
   if (count($line) < 4) continue;
   $xml->startElement('url');
   $xml->writeElement('loc', $line[0]);
   $xml->writeElement('changefreq', $line[1]);
   $xml->writeElement('priority', $line[2]);
   $xml->endElement();
}
$xml->endElement();

echo $xml->outputMemory();
```

Output:

```
<urlset xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
 <url>
  <loc>http://example.com</loc>
  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
  <priority>0</priority>
 </url>
 <url>
  <loc>http://example.com/one</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  <priority>0</priority>
 </url>
 <url>
  <loc>http://example.com/two</loc>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
  <priority>0</priority>
 </url>
</urlset>
```

NOTE: The `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute should be optional.